# Google Drive API - PHP-Client missing trash()-Method?

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I do get the Error "Call to undefined method google_Service_Drive_Resource_Files::trash()" when executing the php-code example from https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/trash.

Also had a look to Google_Service_Drive_Resource_Files and could not find the trash-Method implemented.

So the Google Developer Guide is wrong?

I use v2.2.1 of google-api-php-client

Comment: That is drive v2 method i am not all that sure that the PHP client libary builds for that anymore I am only seeing v3 built.   You should consider moving to google drive v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a problem with the project that builds this library.  It is only bulding a single version of each api that being the newest.   So at this time you can only use Google Drive V3 as Google Drive v2 is not being built

Tracked on the project here:

1. [Drive V2 missing](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/1366)
2. [Support versioned APIs](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/issues/44)